# WiFi connection replace cross connect within datacenter?

Tags: network

Usually datacenter will charge for cross connect, two of our racks is within same zone, does wifi connection stable enough to replace physical cross connect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless the wifi is intended for administrative access, this would not be a great idea.

You will encounter all kinds of interference and increased latency. Your server cabinet is most likely bonded to the ground and essentially amounts to a [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage). Not to mention all the other large metal objects in a datacenter that could cause interference.

The datacenter is also very unlikely to allow you to stick antennas outside of your cabinet to improve the signal.

Point-to-point wireless bridges [such as these](http://www.proxim.com/products/point-to-point-backhaul) work very well and are widely used. However, they are typically deployed on rooftops where unobstructed line of sight can be established and are used for pulling connectivity into a building where fiber is lacking.

Comment: if I use higher power wireless bridges, would it escape from Faraday cage and interference?